# Can [NSApplication sharedApplication] ever return nil?

Tags: objective-c, macos, null, nsapplication, defensive-programming

In a MacOS app in Objective-C is it possible for `[NSApplication sharedApplication]` to return `nil` or is it a safe assumption that this will **never** return `nil`?

The [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/1428360-sharedapplication?language=objc) describes the behavior:

> Returns the application instance, creating it if it doesn’t exist yet.

**However:**

- Is there any possibility to *fail* to create it? For example if the memory for the `NSApplication` object cannot be allocated?
- If such an unexpected error prevents the object from being created would the framework automatically detect this and crash instead of returning `nil`?
- I cannot safely assume that `NSApplication.shared` in Swift being non optional guarantees a non `NULL` return in the Objective-C equivalent as per [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75987263/16217248).

Therefore would the following `if` statement serve **any** purpose or is this redundant? As a C programmer we are taught to be very careful to `NULL` check memory allocations or other operations that could fail even if failure is diminishingly unlikely. But does this concern apply to `[NSApplication sharedApplication]`?

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
int main() {
    if (![NSApplication sharedApplication]) {
        return -1;
    }
    // ...
    [NSApp run];
}
```

My goal is to write **absolutely** correct code, not just good enough in **almost** all cases, while remaining as concise as possible.

Comment: Does the description answer your question? *Returns the application instance, creating it if it doesn’t exist yet.*

Comment: @vadian Could it ever somehow fail to create it?

Comment: No, it can not. In Swift it returns a non-optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sharedApplication` is of **_Nonnull** as the code says and as the documentation seys:

> Summary:
>
> Returns the application instance, creating it if it doesn’t exist yet.

Source: [sharedApplication](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/1428360-sharedapplication?language=objc)

Comment: This answer could be improved with a source, proof, or citation that `sharedApplication` is of `_Nonnull` because I could not find any indication of that in the linked documentation nor in the header file when I jump to the definition of `sharedApplication`.

Comment: @user16217248 
You didn't see `_Nonnull` because the header file is audited `NS_HEADER_AUDIT_BEGIN(nullability, sendability)`. So any simple pointer type will be assumed to be `nonnull`. [Here is the more info about it](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25).