# Why can Objective-C dispatch_group_create() return NULL but not Swift DispatchGroup()?

Tags: swift, objective-c, null, dispatchgroup

I noticed a disparity between the Swift API for dispatch groups and the Objective-C API.

The [`init()` for `DispatchGroup()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup/1452975-init) returns a non optional value.

But the Objective-C [`dispatch_group_create()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1452975-dispatch_group_create) mentions a possibility for a `NULL` return:

> ## Return Value
>
> The newly created group, or NULL on failure.

- What might cause the Objective-C function to fail? What behind the scenes issues could cause the creation of the group to not be possible?
- Why is the Swift version not optional but the Objective-C version is? If creation could fail for any reason why would those same reasons not apply to Swift?

Comment: Does seem odd. One would think that Swift's `DispatchGroup` is just a wrapper around Objective-C's `dispatch_group_t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Objective-C, any object reference can be `nil`, and any call to an object initializer must cope with the possibility that `nil` might be returned.

In Swift, therefore, every Objective-C object would theoretically need to be an Optional — and in Swift 1 this was indeed the case: They were all implicitly unwrapped Optionals. Later, though, every single Objective-C object reference in Swift was hand-tweaked to be either a *normal* Optional or an ordinary non-Optional, depending on whether it could truly ever by `nil` or not.

Well, the object that you get when you call `dispatch_group_create()` therefore *can* theoretically be `nil`, in fact it never will be. The creators of the Swift-style DispatchQueue code knew this, and so the DispatchGroup initializer is not nullable.

Comment: Then why does the documentation say *'NULL on failure'* if it will never ever fail?

Comment: I think that's what I just explained. _Any_ Objective-C initializer can return NULL on failure. That doesn't mean it _will_ and it isn't the (very old) documentation's job to worry about that distinction. All Objective-C code checks to see whether it got `nil`.

Comment: As an example, ObjC considers the possibility that memory may be exhausted and the required data structures cannot be initialized. In practice, it's basically impossible to actually deal with memory exhaustion in ObjC, and no one really does, but it is considered a legitimate non-fatal failure. Swift does not consider memory exhaustion to be a recoverable error.

Comment: Also, there's no need to guess. libdispatch is open source: https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch/blob/469c8ecfa0011f5da23acacf8658b6a60a899a78/src/semaphore.c#L29-L49

Comment: @RobNapier Based on the linked source, they seem to access members of the object pointer without checking if it is `NULL`. So if it fails undefined behavior will have been invoked anyway.